# HTML Post is giving 404 error

Tags: php, html, post

I am posting values from one page to another. It's a very simple process but I am continuously getting the error:

**Not Found
The requested URL /â€œsend_notification.phpâ€ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

Here is my first page:

```
<html>

<body>
<form action=“send_notification.php” method=“post”>
<table>
<tr>
<td>title:</td>
<td><input type=“text” name=“title”/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message: </td>
<td><input type=“text” name=“message”/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my second page:

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$messages=$_POST['message'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
echo $messages;
echo $title;
?>
```

I am confused what is wrong.

Comment: Use proper quotes for your HTML attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the page is requesting the url `http://example.com/“send_notification.php“` rather than `http://example.com/send_notification.php`

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="send_notification.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>title:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="message"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the `“` to a correct html quotes: `"`.
In html (and php) use `'` or `"`.